# WYGWAM error "The file browser is disabled for security reasons..."

Tags: wygwam

When trying to browse files to upload an image I am getting the error:

*The file browser is disabled for security reasons. Please contact your system administrator and check the CKFinder configuration file.*

I am running old versions, but hope there is a quick solution before having to update this old site.
Running:

EE v2.2.1

WYGWAM 2.3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're accessing your CP on the same domain as your site? e.g domain.com/cp and not www.domain.com/cp. Ensure whichever you're using matches that which is set in Admin > General Configuration.